# Access/SQL: How to get the next closest date in Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables that I'd like to join and match a date from table `DATE_GAPS` to the closest next date from table `MISSING_DATES`. The tables are below:

**Table `MISSING_DATES`:**

```
UPC  | Date
-----+----------
1111 | 8/18/2018
1111 | 8/19/2018
1111 | 8/25/2018
1222 | 8/18/2018
1222 | 9/1/2018
```

**Table `DATE_GAPS`:**

```
UPC  | Date
-----+----------
1111 | 8/16/2018
1111 | 8/17/2018
1111 | 8/20/2018
1111 | 8/27/2018
1222 | 8/20/2018
1222 | 9/4/2018
```

**New Table:**

```
UPC  | Date      | Closest Next Date
-----+-----------+------------------
1111 | 8/18/2018 | 8/20/2018
1111 | 8/19/2018 | 8/20/2018
1111 | 8/25/2018 | 8/27/2018
1222 | 8/18/2018 | 8/20/2018
1222 | 9/1/2018  | 9/4/2018
```

Here is the script I currently have but it's taking too long to load:

```
SELECT MISSING_DATES.UPC
  , MISSING_DATES.DATE
  , (
      SELECT MIN(DATE_GAPS.DATE)
      FROM DATE_GAPS
      INNER JOIN MISSING_DATES
        ON DATE_GAPS.UPC = MISSING_DATES.UPC
      WHERE DATE_GAPS.DATE > MISSING_DATES.DATE
    ) AS [Closest Next Date]
FROM MISSING_DATES
  , DATE_GAPS
ORDER BY MISSING_DATES.DATE
  , MISSING_DATES.UPC;
```

I can't figure out how to either optimize the current script or rewrite to get what I want to output.

I have also tried to use the following code which works but it gives me the closest date (before or after):

```
SELECT TOP 1 MISSING_DATES.UPC, MISSING_DATES.DATE, 
DATE_GAPS.DATE, DATE_GAPS.UPC 
FROM MISSING_DATES INNER JOIN DATE_GAPS ON MISSING_DATES.UPC=DATE_GAPS.UPC 
WHERE (((DATE_GAPS.UPC)=[MISSING_DATES].[UPC])) ORDER BY
Abs(DateDiff("d",MISSING_DATES.DATE,DATE_GAPS.DATE));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select md.*,
       (select top 1 dg.date
        from date_gaps as dg
        where dg.upc = md.upc and dg.date >= md.date
        order by dg.date
       ) as [Closest Next Date]
from missing_dates as md;
```

For performance, an index on `data_gaps(upc, date)` would help.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - this seems to work but after it runs it causes Access to crash. Any idea why? Missing_Dates table is ~20k records and Date_Gaps Table is ~147k

Comment: @BenjaminMandowsky . . . I don't know why it would cause MS Access to crash *after* it has run.  I added a comment about an index, which should help performance, though.

Comment: There is an index in the Date_Gaps table already. Can the code be edited to use the index so it performs better?

Comment: @BenjaminMandowsky . . . This query should use the index that I specifically mention in the answer.